# ¿Como poner todo la informacion en una sola ventana visual?

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo un arreglo bidimensional (matriz) donde se guardan datos por ejemplo en este caso una marca de autos y sus modelos, pero necesito que al momento de mostrarme los modelos de los autos los haga en una sola ventana visual.

actualmente me muestra un solo modelo por ventana, es decir.

```
public class Bidimencional
{


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     //Declaracion de arreglo bidemensional
     String[][] marcas_autos = new String[3][5];
     

    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        String marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue una marca de autos");
        
        marcas_autos[i][0] = marca;
        
        for(int x = 0; x<= 4; x++)
        {
            String auto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue el modelo del auto");
            marcas_autos[i][x] = auto;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<= 2; i++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las marcas son;" + marcas_autos[i][0]);
        for(int x = 1; x <=4; x++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las marcas son;" + marcas_autos[i][x]);
        
        }
    }
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar todos los modelos en una única ventana de JOptionPane debes crear una **variable** String e ir **concatenando** los valores (modelos de autos). Una vez realizado esto le **pasas** la **variable** String al JOptionPane.

Las marcas de autos las guardamos en la posición 0 de las columnas, **marcasYmodelos[x][0]**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Bidimencional
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         //Declaracion de arreglo bidemensional
         final int FILAS =3;//constatnte cantidad de filas
         final int COLUMNAS =5;//constatnte cantidad de columnas
         String[][] marcasYmodelos = new String[FILAS][COLUMNAS];

        //completamos matriz
        for(int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++)
        {
            String marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue una marca de autos");

            marcasYmodelos[i][0] = marca;

            for(int x = 1; x < COLUMNAS; x++)
            {
                String auto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue un modelo para la marca "+marca);
                marcasYmodelos[i][x] = auto;
            }
        }
        
        //mostramos matriz
        String modelos ="";
        for(int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Listado de modelos para la marca: " + marcasYmodelos[i][0]);
            //iniciamos en posición 1 ya que en 0 se guarda la marca
            for(int x = 1; x < COLUMNAS; x++)
            {
                modelos +=marcasYmodelos[i][x];//concatenamos modelo
                modelos +="\n";//salto de linea
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los modelos de " + marcasYmodelos[i][0]
                    + " son:\n" + modelos);
            modelos ="";//borramos cadena para la próxima iteración (otra marca)
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias tu respuesta fue muy util, la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo en esto y no tenia ni idea, de nuevo muchas gracias.